# How to geocorrect in qgis?

Tags: qgis, raster, geotiff-tiff

I need to fit a utm wgs84 tiff raster to a topomap in the same projection. I use GCP and it invariably fails. The first raster uncorrected rater superimpose well, the "geocorrected" raster is projected far away. I use the same projection for the project. What's happening?

---

Ok, sorry and thanks for your answer. I have a utm wgs84 image in tiff and toposheet in utm wgs84 in tiff. The image need geocorrection. I open the toposheet in the main qgis screen and I import the image in the georeferencer. I create GCP with the "Enter map coordinates" tool, "From map canvas". This fails: srcX will be almost the same as dstX, the absolute value of srcY will also be very close to the dstY, but srcY is negative. The new geocorrected map is projected in a totally different area.

Comment: Make sure X/Y data is in the correct order.

Comment: Please describe exactly which steps you followed, otherwise we have to guess what could have gone wrong.

Comment: Ok, sorry and thanks for your answer. I have a utm wgs84 image in tiff and toposheet in utm wgs84 in tiff. The image need geocorrection. I open the toposheet in the main qgis screen and I import the image in the georeferencer. I create GCP with the "Enter map coordinates" tool, "From map canvas". This fails: srcX will be almost the same as dstX, the absolute value of srcY will also be very close to the dstY, but srcY is negative. The new geocorrected map is projected in a totally different area.